# When "Ctrl+K, C" to open comment, prevent the unnecessary white-space following slashes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, code-formatting, ionide

When using "Ctrl+K, C" to open a comment,
how to prevent the unnecessary white-space following slashes?

Also when open a new line with <kbd>Enter</kbd> continues commenting.

Comment: Whatunnecessarywhitespace?

Comment: Seems like correct behaviour

Comment: Two slashes starts a line-comment, not two slashes with a white-space, at least in C# and F# it is.

Comment: So it's unnecessary white-space

Comment: type `//my comment` or submit a PR.

Comment: @a_a The point of the "Whatunnecessarywhitespace" comment (which five people, including me, have upvoted) is that while that whitespace may not be necessary according to the *language specification*, most people consider it necessary for *legibility* and would consider it bad style to omit that whitespace. There are many things the language spec allows you to do, like write way too much code on a single line, which are bad style and would annoy your colleagues if you did it in real code. Writing comments `//like this` is one of them, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by vscode rather than F# or Ionide. Ionide simply defines `//` in `language-configuration.json`. So this would have to be achieved via a plugin, or a pull request/feature request.

As an aside, I use `ctrl + /`.

Comment: Oops! Thank you!